# Match argument object that has a property equal to (using Mockk)

Tags: kotlin, mockk

I have looked around for a similar question, but cannot find a solution.

I have a couple of instances to the same type of object. As a simple example, a Pen object. This class contains size (Int) and color (String) properties. I need to mock a function (such as calculatePrice) that takes in this type of object. I would like it to return a result **based on one of the properties**.

```
    every { calculatePrice(pen : Pen) } returns 3
    every { calculatePrice(pen2 : Pen) } returns 4
```

Because this call is nested within another function, I cannot guarantee that the address of the object is the same, so I am attempting to get around this by checking a property value, such as pen.size. If there is a way to make sure the *value* of the object is the same, not the reference, that would solve my problem too.

Using Mockito, I would use argThat(pen -> pen.size() == 2)

Any recommendations would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 18):

`match` should work, see https://mockk.io/#matchers

For example:

```
every { calculatePrice( match { it.size == 2 } ) } returns 3
```

Comment: It works, but the generated message is hideous, anyone who find a better message generator in case of error will take my upvote!